# WCF transmit datatable as binary

Tags: c#, wcf, optimization, service

I need fast transmit data from my wcf service to client.
As SO helps, it means good binary serializer\derializer and data through List
But I've got only XML text of DataTable serialized on service. It's big overhead.

Ok I should move to binary encoding of List. I haven't any DTO, just xml of DataTable.
Could you help me with best practice

PS: At client I need datatable again for processing
PSS: Http,Tcp bindings of wcf service.

Comment: DataTable = overhead.  If you need speed, you need a much simpler model to hold your data.

Comment: If you can give details of the DataTable schema, I *might* be able to implement it as a protobuf-net sample.

Comment: I did some additional investigation into this; see [DataTable – life in the old beast?](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html) which may give you more information to make an informed choice.

Comment: Hello Marc, I try your experemental code from http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/. With ProtoWrite method I have the worst results (time serializng/size output)..

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to try is to gzip the xml and aend via an mtom blob - simply a byte[] via wcf

If the XML is if a fixed schema, I would then consider writing some DTO translation code and send via protobuf-net and MTOM (reversing the translation at the other end).

I have an idea to pack adhoc datatables via protobuf-net <s>but I haven't had chance to implement it yet</s> which I discuss here: [DataTable – life in the old beast?](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html).

Comment: Marc thanks again!!! Your answer are perfect. I will try gzip with mton and track protobuf-net changes

Comment: @Patrik - yes, that link looks oddly familiar. I already added it as a comment to the *question*, though.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the first step in optimizing is getting rid of the DataTables and introducing model objects. Once this is done you could configure your service endpoint to use [netTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx) for optimized binary transfer. Remember that this binding is not interoperable with non .NET clients so you could also have a `basicHttpBinding` endpoint exposed in case you need this.

At the end of the day there should be only model objects involved in the exposed service methods (no DataTables and DataSets):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    SomeModel[] GetModels();
}
```

This being said I would recommend you performing load tests and proving that this is a bottleneck for your application before trying to prematurely optimize it.

Comment: Nettcpbinding is very bloated in real terms. It's efficiency is generally vastly exaggerated.

Comment: Darin, thanks for the answer. But I've got a lot of legacy code, which uses datatable. I can't avoid them by introducing model objects.